# WordPress-hosted blogs inaccessible from Vietnam

Tags: internet-connection

I'm in Vietnam and I am having problems accessing WordPress blogs. As long as it's (something).wordpress.com, I can't open it. I tried using different browsers, different devices (phone, tablets, laptop), different Wi-Fi networks and I still can't open it. I checked the Facebook page of the blog I wanted to open and there aren't any announcements about the page being down for maintenance.

And I also tried to open random WordPress blogs, still didn't work! 3G didn't work either. When trying to access, it shows "can't locate server" message.

I use a MacBook Air with OS X El Capitan.

`8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4` and the IPv6 one given by Google only unblocks Facebook, not WordPress.

Here are the results of the pinging:

```
--- PING lb.wordpress.com (192.0.78.13) 56(84) bytes of data. ---
64 bytes from 192.0.78.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=10.8 ms

--- lb.wordpress.com ping statistics ---                
packets transmitted 4
received            4
packet loss         0 %
time                3004 ms

--- Round Trip Time (rtt) ---
min     10.817 ms
avg     12.096 ms
max     13.296 ms
mdev    0.896 ms.
```

Comment: As far as I know, [the government of Vietnam blocks certain websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Vietnam). Maybe wordpress.com is one of them?

Answer (score 1):

As Hexaholic mentioned, the the Vietnamese government blocks certain websites - a quick google search shows that Wordpress *is* one of those websites.

However, Vietnam's blocks occur at the DNS level, which means they can be easily bypassed.  You should be able to fix this by configuring your network adapter to use Google's DNS servers.

Google's IPV4 addresses are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Google's IPV6 addresses are `2001:4860:4860::8888` and `2001:4860:4860::8844`.

The process of configuring your adapter will vary significantly depending on your operating system.

Comment: I already tried those, they didn't work.

Comment: There's some other ones you can try [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm) - Basically the trick is to find a non-blocked DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can reach your host, may be some firewall by the isp. Try any online free proxy from google and check it. May be censorship by your country. https://hide.me/en/proxy

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome and download a plugin called [Hot Spot Shield Free VPN Proxy-Unblock Sites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotspot-shield-free-vpn-p/nlbejmccbhkncgokjcmghpfloaajcffj?hl=en). It also has [an app](https://www.hotspotshield.com/download/) for various operating systems.